# Bash Grep View Count from Youtube

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I'm trying to make a bash script where I would something like `wget -O youtube.html http://youtube.com`. I'm trying to figure out how to only the view counts with `grep`. I've used `grep [0-9].views youtube.html` but I'm still returning lots of unnecessary lines.

If someone could give me some hints that'd be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can quieten `wget`'s output and pipe straight into grep with a positive lookahead to simply output the view counts:

```
wget -q -O- http://youtube.com | grep -oP "[0-9,]+(?=\sviews)"
```

Answer (score 1):

`grep views youtube.html` worked for me. If you want only the numbers, you could do `grep views youtube.html | cut -f1 -d' '`.

Hope this helps =)